# Is `scalaBinaryVersion` incompatible with `crossScalaVersions` in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm changing a project built against `2.11.7` so it cross-builds against `2.10.5` and `2.11.7`.

The project currently defines a `scalaBinaryVersion := "2.11"` setting, which is causing the following warning:

> Binary version (2.10) for dependency XXX differs from Scala binary
>   version in project (2.11).

I've had a dig, and it seems all other cross-built Scala projects don't specify a `scalaBinaryVersion`.

Are `scalaBinaryVersion` and `crossScalaVersions` mutually exclusive settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there're not mutually exclusive, they're just clashing.

Don't redefine `scalaBinaryVersion`, leave it to its default definition.